# JavaFX login to different pages

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, authentication, mysql-workbench

I am currently working on a login system for my own project. I am very new to java so please don't be harsh.

The problem I have is this:
I got a working login system which works fine but I want to expand it. In my application I have two types of employees. Managers and employees. I want to make a system where if you login as a manager you see a certain page and if you login as a employee you see another page.

So far I got this:
CODE:

Database connection:

```
package databasetesten.connection;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */

public class ConnectionUtil {

Connection conn = null;

public static Connection connectdb() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mhhproject.nl:3306/Management", "root", "root");
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Login applicatie:

```
package databasetesten;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */
public class LoginApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="548.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="databasetesten.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
<Button fx:id="button" layoutX="204.0" layoutY="162.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Login" />
<Label fx:id="label" layoutX="204.0" layoutY="269.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
<TextField fx:id="textEmail" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="65.0" />
<Label layoutX="107.0" layoutY="69.0" text="Username" />
<Label layoutX="107.0" layoutY="119.0" text="Password" />
<PasswordField fx:id="textPassword" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="115.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLMenuEmployee:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">`

</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLMenuManager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController:

```
package databasetesten;

import databasetesten.connection.ConnectionUtil;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Matt Holland
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField textEmail;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField textPassword;

    Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
    Scene scene;

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public FXMLDocumentController() {
        connection = ConnectionUtil.connectdb();
    }

   @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String email = textEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = textPassword.getText().toString();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            infoBox("Enter Correct Email and Password", "Failed", null);
        } else {
            infoBox("Login Successfull", "Success", null);
            Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
            dialogStage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
            dialogStage.close();
           scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resultSet.getIn‌​t(1) == 0 ? "FXMLMenuEmployee.fxml" : "FXMLMenuManager.fxml")));
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);
            dialogStage.show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar, String headerMessage) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle(titleBar);
    alert.setHeaderText(headerMessage);
    alert.setContentText(infoMessage);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}
}
```

The database table called employee looks like this:

```
username      password       function
Bob1          Welcome123     0
Ben1          Bensw123       1
```

So far instance if you login as username: Bob1 and password: Welcome123 You go to the FXMLMenuEmployee. And if you login as username: Bob2 and password: Bensw123 you go to the FXMLMenuManager.

In my FXMLDocumentController I have a line of code:

```
 scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resultSet.getIn‌​t(1) == 0 ? "FXMLMenuEmployee.fxml" : "FXMLMenuManager.fxml")));
```

I thought this piece of code would work but it didn't.
Hopefully someone can help me fix my code so that it works!

Comment: "I thought this piece of code would work but it didn't." This is not a problem statement: what actually happens? In what sense doesn't it work?

Comment: Off topic: don't mix JavaFX and Swing - you should not be using `JOptionPane` in a JavaFX application.

Comment: Sorry James_D for the confussion. The problem with the line of code now is that if I either login with a employee or managers account it takes me to the manager screen

Comment: From the code you posted it would be impossible to tell, but assuming you have something in the FXML files that distinguishes them, did you check what `resultSet.getInt(1)` was returning? And did you really mean `getInt(1)` there? Why `1`???

Comment: I have a piece of text that distinguishes the two fxml files (just some text).

Comment: With the code as it is right now resultSet.getInt(1) takes me to manager screen even when I login as a employee.

Comment: Yes, you said that already. What value is `resultSet.getInt(1)` returning? Why are you passing the value `1` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the table representation you posted:

```
username      password       function
Bob1          Welcome123     0
Ben1          Bensw123       1
```

it seems that

```
resultSet.getInt(1);
```

which gives the value in the first column of the result set, would not be checking the correct field. (Though I would expect an exception, since the field value appears not to be numeric.)

You probably want `resultSet.getInt(3)`, though using the column label instead of the column index is a lot safer:

```
String resource = resultSet.getIn‌​t("function") == 0 ? "FXMLMenuEmployee.fxml" : "FXMLMenuManager.fxml"
scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resource)));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Login extends Application {
    String user = "asad";
    String pw = "786";
    String checkUser, checkPw;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("HOTEL MANAGEMENT");
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds(); //primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED); primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX()); primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY()); primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth()); primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());         BorderPane bp = new  BorderPane();         //Adding  HBox         //bp.setTop(new  Header());         bp.setBottom(new  Footer());         VBox  box_center=new  VBox();

        box_center.setId("box_center"); //Adding  GridPane         GridPane login_grid = new  GridPane();         login_grid.setHgap(15);         login_grid.setVgap(25);        //Implementing  Nodes  for  GridPane         Label lblUserName = new  Label("Username");         final TextField txtUserName = new  TextField();         txtUserName.setPromptText("Enter  Username");         Label lblPassword = new  Label("Password");         final PasswordField passField = new  PasswordField();         passField.setPromptText("Enter  Password");         Button  btnLogin  = new  Button("Login");         final Label lblMessage = new  Label();         //Adding  Nodes  to  GridPane layout         login_grid.add(lblUserName, 0, 1);         login_grid.add(txtUserName, 1, 1);         login_grid.add(lblPassword, 0, 2);         login_grid.add(passField, 1, 2);         login_grid.add(btnLogin, 1, 3);         login_grid.add(lblMessage, 1, 4);         //DropShadow  effect         DropShadow  dropShadow  = new  DropShadow();         dropShadow.setOffsetX(6);         dropShadow.setOffsetY(6);         //Adding  text  and DropShadow  effect  to  it         T ext  login_heading  = new  Text("HOTEL  LOGIN");         login_heading.setFont(Font.font("Courier  New", FontWeight.BOLD, 48));         login_heading.setEffect(dropShadow);         //login_grid.setEffect(dropShadow);         //Adding  text  to  HBox         //hb.getChildren().add(login_heading);         login_grid.add(login_heading, 0, 0, 2,1);         //Add ID's  to  Nodes         bp.setId("bp");         login_grid.setId("login_grid");         btnLogin.setId("btnLogin");         login_heading.setId("login_heading");         //Action  for  btnLogin         btnLogin.setOnAction(new  EventHandler<ActionEvent>()  {          public void handle(ActionEvent  event)          {           checkUser  = txtUserName.getText().toString();           checkPw  = passField.getText().toString();           if(checkUser.equals(user)  &&  checkPw.equals(pw)){            lblMessage.setText("Congratulations!");

        lblMessage.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        Main main = new Main();
        Stage s = new Stage();
        main.start(s);
        s.show();
        primaryStage.hide();
    } else {
        lblMessage.setText("Invalid username or  password");
        lblMessage.setTextFill(Color.RED);
    }
    txtUserName.setText("");
    passField.setText("");
}
});
T ext loginfooterTxt = new Text("©  2017  Hotel Management  Login. All rights  reserved | Designed  by  Indiaone");
loginfooterTxt.getStyleClass().add("loginfooterTxt");
loginfooterTxt.setEffect(dropShadow); //Add HBox  and GridPane layout  to  BorderPane Layout         //bp.setTop(hb);         //login_grid.getChildren().add(heading_sec);         //BorderPane.setAlignment(bp, Pos.TOP_CENTER);         box_center.getChildren().add(0, login_grid);         box_center.getChildren().add(1, loginfooterTxt);         box_center.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);         bp.setCenter(box_center);          //Adding  BorderPane to  the scene and loading  CSS      Scene scene = new  Scene(bp);      scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("login.css").toExternalForm());      primaryStage.setScene(scene);        primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(                  scene.widthProperty().asString().                  concat("  : ").                  concat(scene.heightProperty().asString()));      //primaryStage.setResizable(false);      primaryStage.show();     } } package application; import  javafx.application.Application; import  javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```

Comment: This code isn't human readable. Please edit your answer and use the formatting tools.